# heroku pg:reset breaks everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I was trying to reset the seed data in my heroku database for an app i'm building and the developer site from heroku says to use `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` to do so.

After doing this and migrating my database again `heroku run rake db:migrate` followed by re-seeding with `heroku run rake db:seed` I cannot migrate any apps. even new ones. I don't know if a schema will help. It was not a database problem I was trying to fix, just a removal of repeated records.

Comment: That would be helpful, wouldn't it. Sorry. It is an HTTP error `324: No Response`

Comment: OK, so a very Heroku-specific issue. Time for me to run away.

Comment: Ha, thats what it seemed to me. Thanks for the try though.